# OData free text keyword search by many/all columns

Tags: odata

Is there a way to perform a keyword search by multiple or all columns in OData service?

As an example, I can find all titles with the keyword 'James' using the following URL query:

http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles?$filter=substringof('James', Name)

Is there a way to create some free-text search where it will search by all columns or several columns without explicitly adding each of these conditions such as:

http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles?$filter=substringof('James', Name) or substringof('James', Synopsis) or substringof('James', WebsiteUrl)

Comment: free text search has been added in OData 4 via the $search parameter

Answer (score 2):

Currently OData doesn't support full text search or search across multiple (unspecified) columns as you describe above. The only way from the client is to explicitly add the columns like you have in the second sample.

If you control the server you could implement something like this using a service operation and use the full text search capability of the underlying store (if it has one).